# Making a $.post call with jquery 1.7.1 to a WCF rest service

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, rest, post

So I have the following working:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'user',
    data: '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success!' + data.Id);
    }
});
```

however this fails (which should be equivalent):

```
$.post('user', '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}');
```

Any idea what's wrong?  Is $.post somehow incompatible with WCF rest?

Answer (score 2):

No, the two are not equivalent at all. Look with FireBug, Fiddler, ... and compare the 2 requests. In the second example you are not setting the `contentType: "application/json"` request header. You are not setting it because the `$.post` method doesn't allow you to.

And the server doesn't accept your request because since you are trying to POST to a JSON enabled service, it expects the request to be JSON and of course the client to set the `application/json` content type request header. You are posting some string and since you don't indicate what this string represents through the content type header, the server doesn't know what to do with it and drops the request.

This is to say that you should use `$.ajax` as in the first example to invoke your service. Actually I'd recommend you a slight modification and instead of:

```
data: '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}',
```

use:

```
data: JSON.stringify({"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}),
```

This will ensure that if tomorrow you decide to deal with someone else than `Mr. Jon Doe`, like for example `Mr. Jon O"Hara`, your JSON will still be properly encoded which is what the `JSON.stringify` method does. It is natively built into modern browsers but if you need to support some legacy browsers you could include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to enable it.

Comment: Hi Darin, would this mean:
$.post('user', {"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"})
should work since I'm no longer using the single quotes and .post expects a json object?

Comment: @Jeremy, I don't understand what you are asking me. Are you talking about the `JSON.stringify` method? You should use this only with `$.ajax` as this allows you to specify the content type. It's meaningless to use it with `$.post`. I repeat: `$.post` doesn't allow you to set the content type of the request to `application/json`. Without this HTTP request header the server won;t accept your request. So use `$.ajax`. It's as simple as that. Forget about this `$.post` => that's for doing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests like submitting HTML forms and stuff to ASPX pages for instance.

Comment: I can use $.ajax, but I was hoping for something more shorthand and $.post seemed like the right answer (according to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), but I'll stick with $.ajax like you said.  Thanks.